# Sorting a model has no immediate effect

Tags: qt, signals-slots

I implemented `sort` in a `QAbstractTableModel` subclass. The sorting itself works but the view doesn't change until I hover over the table itself (i.e. not the header). How can I fix this? At first I thought that I also have to emit a signal but couldn't find an appropriate one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following code to sort my model in a project:

```
void MyModel::organize()
{
    if (!cache_ || cache_->empty()) return;
    beginResetModel(); // (a)
    std::stable_sort(cache_->begin(), cache_->end(), compareRow);
    endResetModel(); // (b)
} // end:(MyModel::organize)
```

line (a) tells the model that I'm going to re-organize data, line (b) tells the model that I'm finished, please refresh the associated views.

You may also emit `dataChanged(index, index);` signal.